# YAML parsing in Ruby: How to get array of a certain type of elements?

Tags: ruby, parsing, yaml

I have the following YAML:

```
- name: List of monkeys
- author: Nicolas Raoul
- version: 1
- monkey: Chee-Chee
- monkey: Curious George
- monkey: Mojo
```

How to get the array of monkeys in Ruby? The number of metadata parameters (name, author, ...) is variable.

It would return something like `[Chee-Chee, Curious George, Mojo]`

*Note: I don't want to create a `monkeys` node containing all monkeys as sub-items, because there are many monkeys and I want to keep the file really simple.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your `YAML` looks a little crazy: each of those lines is a `hash` containing one element.  Still, if you're stuck with it, something like this would get you an array of monkey names:

```
require 'yaml'

data = YAML.load(DATA.read)
p data.map { |row| row['monkey'] }.compact

__END__
- name: List of monkeys
- author: Nicolas Raoul
- version: 1
- monkey: Chee-Chee
- monkey: Curious George
- monkey: Mojo
```

Obviously you could load the `YAML` from anywhere, it doesn't have to be in your DATA block.

Comment: I am new to YAML, so any suggestion is welcome :-) The list will be edited by the customer, so it has to be dead simple. Note: each monkey has a few more attribute that I did not write here for brevity.

Comment: Your answer is valid for the question as I had asked it. My assumption that I could ignore monkey attributes for brevity proves wrong, so I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578370