# YAML parsing in Ruby: How to get only a certain type of elements?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have the following YAML:

```
- name: List of monkeys
- author: Nicolas Raoul
- version: 2
- monkey: 
   - name: Chee-Chee
   - age: 2
- monkey:
   - name: Curious George
   - age: 6
   - food: bananas
- monkey:
   - name: Mojo
   - food: peanuts
```

In Ruby, how to get the monkeys?
The number of metadata parameters in the preamble (name, author, ...) is variable.

It would return something like:

```
[{"monkey"=>[{"name"=>"Chee-Chee"}, {"age"=>2}]}, {"monkey"=>[{"name"=>"Curious George"}, {"age"=>6}, {"food"=>"bananas"}]}, {"monkey"=>[{"name"=>"Mojo"}, {"food"=>"peanuts"}]}]
```

In XML/XPath I would simply write `/monkey`, but what is the syntax with YAML/Ruby ?

*Note: I don't want to create a `monkeys` node containing all monkeys as sub-items, because there are many monkeys and the clients will edit the file to add more, so I want to keep the file really simple. I am new to YAML so a better organization might be needed, but brevity is paramount, in particular I don't want to increase the number of sub-levels.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Enumerator's `#select` method to return just the monkeys from your collection.  If you have your parsed YAML object in a variable called `your_yaml`, this code would return what you are asking for:

`your_yaml.select { |item| item['monkey'] }`

You probably don't need the hyphens in the second level.  If you change this...

```
- monkey: 
   - name: Chee-Chee
   - age: 2
```

Into this:

```
- monkey: 
    name: Chee-Chee
    age: 2
```

The monkey's properties will be a hash, instead of an array of hashes.  I'd imagine this is more useful to you.